# List Comprehension with two for loops

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension, nested-loops

```py
letters = list('xyz')
pattern = []
for i in range(len(letters)):    
       for j in range(1,5):     
           pattern.append(letters[i]*j)
pattern = ['x', 'xx', 'xxx', 'xxxx', 'y', 'yy', 'yyy', 'yyyy', 'z', 'zz', 'zzz', 'zzzz']
```

How can i write this code in list comprehension format?

Answer (score 3):

You have most of your building blocks, just got to piece it together!

```py
letters = list('xyz')
pattern = []
```

> `[pattern.append(letters[i]*j) for i in range(len(letters)) for j in range(1,5)]`

```py
print(pattern)
['x', 'xx', 'xxx', 'xxxx', 'y', 'yy', 'yyy', 'yyyy', 'z', 'zz', 'zzz', 'zzzz']
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
[i*j for i in 'xyz' for j in range(1,5)]
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: he asked how to get this output ['x', 'xx', 'xxx', 'xxxx', 'y', 'yy', 'yyy', 'yyyy', 'z', 'zz', 'zzz', 'zzzz'] through list comprehension and this  code  [ i*j for i in 'xyz' for j in range(1,5) ]  gets the required output.

Answer (score 0):

For output:

> `['x','y','z','xx','yy','zz','xxx','yyy','zzz']`

code:

```
[l*i for l in 'xyz' for i in range(1,4)]
```

For output:

> `['x','xx','y','yy','z','zz']`

code:

```
[l*i for i in range(1,3) for l in 'xyz']
```

Answer (score 0):

for output

```
['x', 'xx', 'xxx', 'xxxx', 'y', 'yy', 'yyy', 'yyyy', 'z', 'zz', 'zzz', 'zzzz']
```

code ---

```
[i*j for i in 'xyz' for j in range(1,5)]
```

for output

```
['x', 'y', 'z', 'xx', 'yy', 'zz', 'xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz', 'xxxx', 'yyyy', 'zzzz']
```

code---

```
[i*j for j in range(1,5) for i in 'xyz']
```

Just interchange i,j

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).